# Setup project custom action reading checkboxes

Tags: c#, .net, setup-project

I have checkboxes and a dialogue added.

I need to be able to read the state of the boxes from a custom action. I also need the path which I have but I can't find how to read the state of the checkboxes.

How can this be done?

```
public override void Commit(IDictionary savedState)
{
    base.Commit(savedState);
    String TargetDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Context.Parameters["AssemblyPath"]);
    MessageBox.Show(TargetDirectory);
    // Code needed to read the checkboxes!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
in custom Actions add
/tool="[XYZ] " /MyInfo="[ABC] "

where XYZ and ABC are the CheckboxNProperty

then read them in in the custom action above thus

MessageBox.Show(Context.Parameters["XYZ"]);